# loop until key is pressed and repeat

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, keyboard, pynput

Im trying to loop a print when a key is pressed and stop when another key is pressed.

Also I dont want to exit the program, it must continue listening for a key.

*Problem: But what I get is a infinite loop because it cant listen to a another key while loop is True!*

```
from pynput import keyboard
    
def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.f9:
        while True:
            print("loading")
    if key == keyboard.Key.f10:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

[Im using pynput, docs here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html)

**EDIT**

I did explained wrong one part, I wanted to do a loop when a certain key ***WAS*** pressed.

Comment: don't use `while True` because it blocks `Listener`. You have to run `while` in separated `Thread` and it will need some variable to stop it - ie. `while running` instead of `while True`. And you have to use `on_release` to set `running = False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run `while True` (or any long-running function) inside `on_press`
because it blocks `Listener`. You have to run it in separated `thread`.

You need `on_press` to create and start `thread`.
And `on_release` to stop `thread`.
It needs global variable. ie. `running` for this.

I use `datetime` only to see if it displays new line or not.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
import datetime

# --- functions ---

def loading():
    while running:
         print("loading", datetime.datetime.now()) #, end='\r')
    
def on_press(key):
    global running  # inform function to assign (`=`) to external/global `running` instead of creating local `running`

    if key == keyboard.Key.f9:
        running = True
        # create thread with function `loading`
        t = threading.Thread(target=loading)
        # start thread
        t.start()
        
    if key == keyboard.Key.f10:
        # stop listener
        return False

def on_release(key):
    global running  # inform function to assign (`=`) to external/global `running` instead of creating local `running`
    
    if key == keyboard.Key.f9:
        # to stop loop in thread
        running = False
        
#--- main ---

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: you don't have to put my solution in your question. You marked my answer as accepted so everyone know that my answer resolved your problem. And if you used my code to create better solution for your problem then put your code as another answer and add i.e `based on @furas code`

Answer (score 0):

A solution for when a Key was pressed. `based on @furas code`

```
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
import datetime, time

# --- functions ---

def loading():
    while running:
        print("loading", datetime.datetime.now()) #, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
    
def on_press(key):
    global running  # inform function to assign (`=`) to external/global `running` instead of creating local `running`

    if key == keyboard.Key.f9:
        running = True
        # create thread with function `loading`
        t = threading.Thread(target=loading)
        # start thread
        t.start()
        
    if key == keyboard.Key.f10:
        # to stop loop in thread
        running = False

    if key == keyboard.Key.f11:
        # stop listener
        return False
        
#--- main ---

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```