# Stop While Loop mid execution in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, wait, pynput

I am trying to stop a while loop mid execution, if I reverse the value of 'runWhile' mid execution it simply waits until it's over.

*Problem:* I need it to stop **immediately** whenever I press f10 on the keyboard.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
import datetime, time

def exec():
    while runWhile:
        print("There I go")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("I overtaken")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("You cant stop me until I finish")
        
def on_press(key):
    global runWhile # inform function to assign (`=`) to external/global `running` instead of creating local `running`

    if key == keyboard.Key.f5:
        runWhile = True
        t = threading.Thread(target=exec)
        t.start()
    if key == keyboard.Key.f10:
        # to stop loop in thread
        print("loading STOPPED", datetime.datetime.now()) #, end='\r')
        runWhile = False

    if key == keyboard.Key.f11:
        # stop listener
        print("listener TERMINATED", datetime.datetime.now()) #, end='\r')
        return False
        
        
#--- main ---
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

[Im using pynput, docs here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html)

[`based on @furas code`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196634/loop-until-key-is-pressed-and-repeat/66199118#66199118)

Comment: If you mean to just terminate the whole program, wouldn't a sys.exit() call suffice?

Comment: @thesturggler Yes, I suppose that would work but if I wanted to terminate the program I could just return false, like in "f11" option.
I want to stop just the specific while loop and not the listener/whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I made. I created my own delay function as follows:

```
def delay(amount): #delay time in seconds
    for i in range(int(amount*60)):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if runWhile == False:
            return True
            break
```

You would replace your delay(3) with

```
if delay(3):
    break
```

This would wait 3 seconds, however if during that time, runWhile was false, it will break out of the loop. Your code would look like this:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
import datetime, time

def delay(amount): #delay time in seconds
    for i in range(int(amount*60)):
      time.sleep(0.01)
      if runWhile == False:
        return True
        break

def exec():
    while runWhile:
        print("There I go")
        if delay(3):
          break
        print("I overtaken")
        if delay(3):
          break
        print("You cant stop me until I finish")
        
def on_press(key):
    global runWhile # inform function to assign (`=`) to external/global `running` instead of creating local `running`

    if key == keyboard.Key.f5:
        runWhile = True
        t = threading.Thread(target=exec)
        t.start()
    if key == keyboard.Key.f10:
        # to stop loop in thread
        print("loading STOPPED", datetime.datetime.now()) #, end='\r')
        runWhile = False

    if key == keyboard.Key.f11:
        # stop listener
        print("listener TERMINATED", datetime.datetime.now()) #, end='\r')
        return False
        
        
#--- main ---
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```